# Implementation of RequestBody for POJO objects (XML) android

Tags: java, android, soap, retrofit, okhttp

Hi i want to make api for my soap server written in php for android with retrofit library.

I have created interface

```
public interface SoapApi {
    @Headers({
            "Content-Type: application/soap+xml",
            "Accept-Charset: utf-8"
    })
    @POST("/index.php")
    public DeviceCredentials test(@Body RequestEnvelope body);
}
```

and RequestEnvelope for each request to api

```
@Root(name = "Envelope")
@NamespaceList({
        @Namespace(reference = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", prefix = "s"),
        @Namespace(reference = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/", prefix = "soapenc"),
        @Namespace(reference = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/", prefix = "soap"),
        @Namespace(reference = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/", prefix = "wsdl")
})
public class RequestEnvelope {

    @Element(name = "Body")
    private RequestBody aBody;

    public RequestBody getBody(){
        return aBody;
    }

    public void setBody(RequestBody body){
        aBody = body;
    }
}
```

And my POJO class

```
@Root(name = "DeviceCredentials")
public class DeviceCredentials {

    @Element(name="UUID")
    public String UUID;

    @Element(name="OSType")
    public String OSType;
}
```

i want to set DeviceCredentials class as body of requestEnvelope but i dont know how to create RequestBody implementation to make correct request.

Can you help me please?